# Parsing syslog to count specific values

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

Got a large syslog file consisting of messages like this one:

> Dec 15 06:26:34 titan kernel: [1710994.114000] Drop_43 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:04:23:b7:c1:26:00:06:f6:5f:02:7f:08:00 SRC=52.53.123.183 DST=108.249.31.54 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=60 ID=20977 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=1 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0

I have to find out 10 most active IPs and print ports which these IPs accessed most.

Managed to count top 10 most active IPs with this one -

```
cat syslog| grep SRC | awk '{print$11}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

and it gives something like that

> 2528 SRC=93.65.51.154
>      1860 SRC=162.31.151.223

I also counted most accessed ports with this input

```
cat syslog | awk '{FS="DPT="};{print$2}'| awk '{FS=" "};{print $1}'| sort -n| uniq -c| sort -rn| head -10
```

Now i need to somehow combine these two to get my parsing done right way. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output shall be something like -

Comment: I cannot understand why use `sort -n` for sorting non numerical values (SRC=)

Comment: Have you tried some new code to combine thos two ones?

Comment: No, currently im thinking on how to combine them. The goal is to parse it and the final result should be something like - <Ip> - list of most accesed ports from most used to least. Like - 192.168.44.33 - 22 21 3389

Comment: `(command1 ; command2) > output `

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered collecting your data into associated arrays, then use asort() in an END block to order by occurrence. Finally, print the top 10 entries of each array. Would you like me to suggest some code, or is that inspiration enough?

There's a number of 'crimes' in your code. The first is the classic 'useless use of cat'. But that's being cheeky, and I apologise. I guess the real point here is, you're barely using awk when it could perform every component of the task. No need to grep, sort, uniq, head etc. Do you want to try to turn it all completely into an awk script yourself, or do you need concrete help?

EDIT: here's a script I banged up. I generated a 1000 line test-case file that matches your data. Cut-n-paste the code samples below, in order, into one file called `yourname`, and you'll be able to run it as

```
./yourname syslog
```

and don't forget to run `chmod a+rx yourname` to make it executable.

By the way, I haven't used the asort() as I first suggested, because it simultaneously turned out to be unnecessary and also more trouble than it's worth, for reasons I won't go into here.

To start:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
```

Any script starting with #! will run the nominated command instead of the ordinary shell. Arguments are allowed; awk needs -f to be told which file to read. It will also be given this file's name by the shell. Fortunately, awk sees # as a comment, which is convenient...

First thing is to gather the data. I'm collecting into two arrays; the first counts the hits on each IP address, and the 2nd counts the hits on each port for each IP address.

The first pattern shown here filters only lines of interest. IF your syslog has other lines that accidentally match, you'll need to make the `/SRC=/` pattern strong enough to only and exactly match your chosen lines.

Within the block, the fields are split on = so that just the plain numbers can be stored in the arrays.

```
/SRC=/ {
    split($11, ipa, /=/)
    split($20, porta, /=/)
    IP = ipa[2]
    port = porta[2]
    IPhits[IP]++
    IPports[IP][port]++
}
```

That block will be executed for each line that matches the pattern. When awk gets to the end, it will run any block marked by `END`.

PROCINFO can be used to control the sequence of items are presented when `for ... in` is used to iterate over arrays. I'm setting it to run in descending order of the array elements, which conveniently suits both loops.

I have a simple counter limiting the IP to the top 10 IP addresses, and another counter limiting how many ports it prints per each IP. Because of PROCINFO has been set, both loops will run through highest-values first.

The string to be printed is built up one piece at a time. You are probably aware that strings are glued together in awk just by putting them near each other - that's the `buf = buf sep p` line.

```
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    i = 0
    for(ip in IPhits) {
        # limit of 10 IP addresses to report
        if(i++ == 10) break
        buf = ip
        sep = " - "
        j = 0
        for(p in IPports[ip]) {
            # limit of 10 ports per IP
            if(j++ == 10) break
            buf = buf sep p
            sep = " "
        }
        print buf
    }
}
```

Anything in there that doesn't make sense?